# Why does this sorting algorithm fail?

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I developed the below algorithm to sort the array of dictionary items.

```
guard var imageUrlString = anyImage.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }

var values = [AnyObject]()
var keys = [String]()
var done = false
var j = 1

while !done {
    for i in imageUrlString {
        print(i.key, " this is the key")
        if "media\(j)" == i.key {
            values.append(i.value)
            keys.append(i.key)
            print(i, " This is teh i for in if ")
            if imageUrlString.count == j {
                done = true
                break;
            }
            j+=1
        } else {
            print("No,,.")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, for example, every time the first media is an image, it will loop forever. How can I solve that so that the algorithm can effectively sort the under all conditions?

Comment: Well, its seems that you may getting a count different than `j`; therefore, your `done` flag never chances state and keeps looping.You could change the while loop to something that quits after a certain number of tries such as a for loop (just as a precaution). Second, do you need the while loop? Why would you read the same array `imageUrlString` over and over again?

Comment: This code seems pretty inefficient. Why not simply create an array of the keys and sort that using the in-built sort function?

Comment: @Paulw11 if you suggest an option I can test it, but I have been down that road in the past, and for watever reason I dont think i found anything that worked and so I created this which 90% of the time works, but of course 10% is a big number

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to show the input data and the output you are after. Is your problem that you want a numerical sort of the suffix, not a lexical sort?

Comment: @Paulw11 check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're really creating two parallel arrays: `keys` and `values`.

I went with creating those two arrays, sorted.  Here's an example

```
var imageUrlString = [String: AnyObject]()
imageUrlString["media3"] = "whatever 3 content" as AnyObject
imageUrlString["media7"] = "whatever 7 content" as AnyObject
imageUrlString["media1"] = "whatever 1 content" as AnyObject

let keys = Array(imageUrlString.keys).sorted()
var values = [AnyObject]()

keys.forEach {
    values.append(imageUrlString[$0]!)
}

print(keys)
print(values)
```